# 'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Tengo el siguiente error en un query de laravel, el query que ejecuto es el siguiente.

```
$usuarioE->roles()->update(['kaseya_rol_user.state'=>0]);
```

y el error que me arroja es

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'updated_at' i
  n field list is ambiguous (SQL: update `kaseya_roles` inner join `kaseya_ro
  l_user` on `kaseya_roles`.`id` = `kaseya_rol_user`.`rol_id` set `kaseya_rol
  _user`.`state` = 0, `updated_at` = 2017-06-21 22:03:59 where `kaseya_rol_us
  er`.`user_id` = 11)
```

Se que se podria solucionar especificando el nombre de la tabla para updated_at pero no se como hacerlo si ese campo lo añade laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solucion parte de que la relacion que tengo es de muchos a muchos

Un usuario tiene vario roles y un rol tiene varios usuarios.

En la tabla pivote existe un campo llamado state que sirve para saber el estado del rol del usuario asi llevo un historial de los roles que tuvo.

como lo que necesito es actualizar precisamente es ese campo del rol que ya no tenga el usuario.

Entonces voy a utilizar el metodo **updateExistingPivot** el cual actualiza recisamente los campos que se le indiquen de una tabla pivote lo use de la siguiente forma.

```
  $usuarioE->roles()->updateExistingPivot($rolTMP->id,['state'=>0]);
```

por consiguiente me toca saber primero el id del rol al cual tengo que actualizar por eso la variable **$rolTMP->id**.

> En la pregunta se quería actualizar todos los roles del usuario de un solo golpe, con esta solución es necesario saber cuales son los roles del usuario luego recorrerlos y aplicar el anterior query.

Answer (score 0):

Infortunadamente no hay solución sencilla por ahora utilizando Eloquent, aparte de utilizar el Query Builder para generar la misma consulta.

Dicho bug fue solucionado en un momento para MySQL, pero el fix no funcionó para PostgreSQL, por lo cual fue revertida corrección.

Puedes ver una solución posible usando Eloquent en esta pregunta de SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25325707/495103

Aquí está el enlace hacia el reporte del bug en GitHub: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13909

Comment: Pues actualmente el motor de db que utilizo el mysql.

Comment: Tal y como lo expuse, no hay solución sencilla aparte de realizar la misma consulta por el Query Builder, o no usar timestamps en dicho modelo / tabla.

Comment: Gracias, como solución utilice la función updateExistingPivot

Comment: Puedes agregar la solución como respuesta para compartirla con futuros visitantes.